Saying Baruch Shem after possible Bracha Levatala
When you make a bracha in vain, you're supposed to recite Baruch Shem afterwards. What if you're not sure it was in vain? Normally, you wouldn't recite a bracha in case of doubt, but what if you did so erroneously, or if it was a case of safek d'oraisa or sfek sfeika? Would it still be appropriate to say Baruch Shem to cover your bases?

What do you have to lose?

@DoubleAA I'm not sure, but by that logic maybe we should say it after every bracha, just in case it's unnecessary according to some opinion. One concern I had (admittedly without basis) was whether it could be seen as "denigrating" the bracha by implication.

@shmosel Seems likely there are better things you can do with your time and energy than worry there may be opinions that no one has ever heard of.

We say baruch shem after bracha on tefillin shel rosh because of doubt. If its a real safek, there would be no reason not to say it. Only when it might be a problem of hefsek we wouldnt say it.
